# Binding checkbox selected value textbox to different property than properties bound to dropdown

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

My combobox is bound to 3 properties (IsVisited, Address and City):

```
<ComboBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,25,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisited}" Width="150" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" Width="100" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I want to create a wpf combo box with drop down containing two columns

1. IsVisited (checkbox)
2. City (string)

The   selected textbox portion of the combobox should only display the 'Address'. Does any one know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem and I have achieved your task.

This is the initial view.

[image]

Then after selecting Kegalla,

[image]

I think this is what you need.

1. Define a `view model` for the ComboBoxItem. (In my case I created a class called `MyComboBoxItem` and include properties namely `HasVisited, Address, City, TextBoxValue`)
2. In your main view model, define a `property` to bind the ComboBox `ItemsSource` (I defined a property called `ComboBoxItems`) and another property to bind the `SelectedItem` of the ComboBox (I defined a property called `SelectedComboBoxItem`).
3. In the selection change method, implment your logic to set the texbox.

Here is my `XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="ComboboxSelectedItemChange.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ComboboxSelectedItemChange.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Combo box test" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem}">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HasVisited}" Width="30" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBoxValue}" Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeSelectionCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And this is my `Main View model` which binds to the above view

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Declarations

    private ObservableCollection<MyComboBoxItemViewModel> comboBoxItems;
    private MyComboBoxItemViewModel selectedComboBoxItem;

    private ICommand changeSelectionCommand;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the combo box items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The combo box items.</value>
    public ObservableCollection<MyComboBoxItemViewModel> ComboBoxItems
    {
        get
        {
            return comboBoxItems;
        }
        set
        {
            comboBoxItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboBoxItems");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the selected combo box item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The selected combo box item.</value>
    public MyComboBoxItemViewModel SelectedComboBoxItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedComboBoxItem;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedComboBoxItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedComboBoxItem");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the change selection command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The change selection command.</value>
    public ICommand ChangeSelectionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (changeSelectionCommand == null)
            {
                changeSelectionCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ChangeSelection(),
                    null);
            }
            return changeSelectionCommand;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //Add some dummy data

        this.ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<MyComboBoxItemViewModel>();

        MyComboBoxItemViewModel item1 = new MyComboBoxItemViewModel();
        item1.HasVisited = false;
        item1.Address = "123, Matara";
        item1.City = "Matara";
        item1.TextBoxValue = item1.City;
        this.ComboBoxItems.Add(item1);

        MyComboBoxItemViewModel item2 = new MyComboBoxItemViewModel();
        item2.HasVisited = false;
        item2.Address = "125, Colombo";
        item2.City = "Colombo";
        item2.TextBoxValue = item2.City;
        this.ComboBoxItems.Add(item2);

        MyComboBoxItemViewModel item3 = new MyComboBoxItemViewModel();
        item3.HasVisited = false;
        item3.Address = "465, Kegalle";
        item3.City = "Kegalle";
        item3.TextBoxValue = item3.City;
        this.ComboBoxItems.Add(item3);

        this.SelectedComboBoxItem = item2;

        this.ComboBoxItems.Where(item => item == this.SelectedComboBoxItem).First().TextBoxValue = this.SelectedComboBoxItem.Address;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the selection.
    /// </summary>
    private void ChangeSelection()
    {
        foreach (var comboBoxitem in this.ComboBoxItems)
        {
            this.ComboBoxItems.Where(item => item == comboBoxitem).First().TextBoxValue = comboBoxitem.City;
        }

        this.ComboBoxItems.Where(item => item == this.SelectedComboBoxItem).First().TextBoxValue = this.SelectedComboBoxItem.Address;
        this.ComboBoxItems.Where(item => item == this.SelectedComboBoxItem).First().HasVisited = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And this is the `MyComboBoxItemViewModel`

```cs
public class MyComboBoxItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{ 
    #region Declarations

    private bool hasVisited;
    private string address;
    private string city;
    private string textBoxValue;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance has visited.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance has visited; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool HasVisited
    {
        get
        {
            return hasVisited;
        }
        set
        {
            hasVisited = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HasVisited");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The address.</value>
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return address;
        }
        set
        {
            address = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the city.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The city.</value>
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            city = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("City");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the text box value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The text box value.</value>
    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            return textBoxValue;
        }
        set
        {
            textBoxValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TextBoxValue");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat hacky solution is to check whether or not your `DataTemplate` is inside a `ComboBoxItem` and hide the unwanted values when it's not:

```
             <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisited}" Width="150" x:Name="chk"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Width="100"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" Width="100" x:Name="City"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="City" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="chk" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```